# Selected value in javascript prompt

Tags: javascript, user-input

I'm waiting for user input like this:

```
prompt('hello', 'world');
```

I don't understand why my prompt *defaultText* 'world' is selected.

Not a big deal, just curious, but I'd like to focus on first character without selection.
Is there some kind of *placeholder* for javascript *prompt* box or a way to do it (in pure javascript) ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about UX and browser design, not programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's a UX feature. The default is "world" but if I wanted to override it, I can just start typing, it saves me from selecting all of it. If I wanted to append to it, all I need to do is press the left arrow.

Comment: That makes sense. Not really good looking however. This kind of box isn't very user friendly anyway...

Comment: @TGrif Both `confirm()` and `alert()` and the like use OS level alert boxes, they should be reserved for super serious, I NEED YOUR DECISION RIGHT NOW USER, NOTHING ELSE YOU'RE CURRENTLY DOING MATTERS type of input. Which is why it's **not** a good tool to use in a lot of the cases. Normally, to receive input from the user, you'd just use a form.

Answer (score 0):

```
prompt(text,defaultText)
```

The default input text shown as selected to save user time to override it easily. All browsers are doing same except Safari.

Comment: Seems I gonna need to find another way to get user input... I will look at Safari's way to do it, maybe interesting.